# How to Access Multiple Items in a List in Python?

Tags: list, python-2.7, loops

I am new to Python.

I have a list that I would like to access the i and i+1 items for each iteration in a loop.

```
stress = [100,110,120,130,140,150]
stress_range = []

The algorithm that I used in C was:

for (i=0, i<6; i++)
{
 stress_range[i] = stress[i] - stress[i+1]
}
```

I've been Googling and StackOverflowing for the way of implementing this in Python but to no avail.

Would you be able to advice me please or point me to the documentation to do this?

Thank you.
Regards,
Kenneth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always write C in Python,

```
stress_range = []
for i in range(len(stress)-1):
    stress_range.append(stress[i] - stress[i+1])
```

You need to declare `stress_range` because otherwise it won't be a list when you call the `.append` method.  Alternatively,

```
stress_range = []
for i, stress in enumerate(stress[1:], 1):
    stress_range.append(stress - stress[i])
```

Comment: Thanks James, I did try the range and len combination but I couldnt get it to work, but your method is elegant and I've implemented it., thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just a disclaimer, I am by no means a python developer and this may not be the most optimize way of solving this issue. After poking around for 5 mins, here is a possible solution.

Things to note:

1. The last element of the array will subtract the first element of the
   array, by using the modular function.
2. You may remove the print statement for debugging.

-

```
stress = [100,110,120,130,140,150]
stress_range = []

for index, elem in enumerate(stress):
    current_element = elem
    next_element = stress[(index + 1) % len(stress)]
    print "{0}: {1}".format(current_element, next_element)
    stress_range.append(current_element - next_element)

print '***'

for i in stress_range:
    print i

print '***'
```

Comment: Kevin, thanks for the answer. I did try to enumerate but I guess where I stuck was I was always getting the error message "list index out of range" which you solved by using the modulus over the list length. Thanks for the lesson in Python Code Ninja.

Comment: By the way, I am Kenny =). You are welcome, would appreciate if you could upvote if you accept it as an answer